# Callback Function Between Parent and Child Component

Tags: reactjs

I have problem to pass callback function between parent and child components. My child component is a list of numbers. I am trying to create a pagination component. I got error message in the Pages.js component when click on the list number -TypeError: undefined has no properties
Below is my code, thanks in advance.
App.js

```
class App extends Component {

  state = {
    CurrentPage: 1,
    Items: []
  }
  handlePageClick = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      currentPage: Number(event.target.id)
    });
  }
  render() {
    const pageNumbers = 10;
    return ( <
      Pages pageNumbers = {
        pageNumbers
      }
      onClick = {
        this.handlePageClick
      }
      /> 
    );

  }


}
```

Pages.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Pages = ({
  pageNumbers,
  handlePageClick
}) => {
  return (

    pageNumbers.map(number => < li key = {
        number
      }
      id = {
        number
      }
      onClick = {
        () => this.handlePageClick(number)
      } > {
        number
      } <
      /li>)
    );

  }
}
export default Pages;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off `this` is a reserved keyword that can only be used in class components. Second you're passing `onClick` prop in the Pages component. So the `<li>` tag should call `onClick` instead of `this.handlePageClick`.

The code below should work without changing anything in the App component.

```
const Pages = ({
  pageNumbers,
  onClick
}) => {

return (

pageNumbers.map(number => 
  <li key={number}
    id={number}
    onClick={onClick}
  >
    {number}  
  </li>)
  );

  }
}
```

Comment: Great, this works! I passed handlePageClick to the Child component instead of onClick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do remove the arg event and only set your state with the num you get.

```
handlePageClick=(num)=> {
   this.setState({
     currentPage: Number(num)
});
```